# Android Xamarin - cannot install app to my phone

Tags: android, .net, xamarin, apk

I have creaded simple app, which calculate some data what user write to app. Data are saved in sqlite. When I deploy app on my phone, everything is ok, but when i put .apk file to my phone and install it and start it, app drop on start. I tried allow all permissions, but it doesn't help. What is wrong?

Comment: Did you already try anything? Is there any output in the logcat?

Comment: How can i open logcat?

Comment: Connect your device to your computer, enable USB Debugging and run adb logcat in the terminal. For more details have a look in the documentation: https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/logcat.html.

Comment: I have it. I think, reason of dropping is Not assemblies found in.. What should i do with it?

Comment: It is very difficult to help you as the question is currently stated. As others have suggested, try to investigate logcat. That may give you an idea of what is wrong. Afterwards, if you still can't solve the issue, the update the question with the output that you're given.

Comment: I solved it. I just had to uncheck Use shared runtime in manifest android options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. I just unchecked Use shared runtime in manifest android options.